# undefined method with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many

I have 2 models with a one-to-many association: User and Recipe. the User class has_many :recipes while the Recipe class belongs_to :user. I've already run the migration, reloaded the rails console, and checked to make sure that user_id is a column in the recipes table. Still, I get an undefined method error when I try to append a recipe to a user:

```
2.0.0-p598 :047 > user.recipes << Recipe.first
NoMethodError: undefined method `recipes' for #<User:0x00000004326fa0>
```

here is the migration code (I've already run rake db:migrate):

```
class AddUserIdToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :recipes, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Here is the User model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :recipes
end
```

Here is the Recipe model code:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :body

  belongs_to :user

  def long_title
    "#{title} - #{published_at}"
  end
end
```

Why does recipes still show up as an undefined method?

Comment: "Have you tried to turn it off and on again ?" (talking about your Rails server)

Comment: In your migration, try adding a ':user_id, :integer' to another column under recipes and remove the :user_id, :integer from the recipe column. Reset migration and rake it again.

Comment: thanks, that worked (turning rails server on and off). Still kind of confused what the rails server has to do with any of this though. All I'm doing is editing the database, which I have seen changes in without ever booting up the rails server

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your console:

```
irb(main):007:0> user = User.new first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'
=> #<User id: nil, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):008:0> user.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "first_name", "last_name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-01-19 21:14:33.489371"], ["first_name", "John"], ["last_name", "Doe"], ["updated_at", "2015-01-19 21:14:33.489371"]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):009:0> r = Recipe.new name: 'oooohh awesome', description: 'my description goes here'
=> #<Recipe id: nil, name: "oooohh awesome", description: "my description goes here", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>
irb(main):010:0> r.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "recipes" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-01-19 21:15:16.548090"], ["description", "my description goes here"], ["name", "oooohh awesome"], ["updated_at", "2015-01-19 21:15:16.548090"]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):011:0> user.recipes << Recipe.first
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes"   ORDER BY "recipes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "recipes" SET "updated_at" = ?, "user_id" = ? WHERE "recipes"."id" = 1  [["updated_at", "2015-01-19 21:15:49.181586"], ["user_id", 1]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes"  WHERE "recipes"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Recipe id: 1, name: "oooohh awesome", description: "sper long deskdk", created_at: "2015-01-19 21:10:24", updated_at: "2015-01-19 21:15:49", user_id: 1>]>
irb(main):012:0> user.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):013:0> user.recipes
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Recipe id: 1, name: "oooohh awesome", description: "sper long deskdk", created_at: "2015-01-19 21:10:24", updated_at: "2015-01-19 21:15:49", user_id: 1>]>
irb(main):014:0> user.recipes.first
=> #<Recipe id: 1, name: "oooohh awesome", description: "sper long deskdk", created_at: "2015-01-19 21:10:24", updated_at: "2015-01-19 21:15:49", user_id: 1>
irb(main):015:0>
```

you can see that `Recipe.first` has been inserted into `user.recipes` and its saved.

I made two models similar to yours, and have exactly the same setup as you. You can follow code above to write your controllers.